# Switching between alternate CSS stylesheets - what are all the available settings?

Tags: css, css3, rel-alternate

### What are all the available settings for stylesheet `<link>` elements?

When deploying CSS stylesheet `<link>` elements, what are all the available settings?

A **persistent** stylesheet looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/my-stylesheet.css" />
```

I *think* the following settings are correct:

1. including a `title` makes the stylesheet **preferred**
2. including a `title` and `rel="alternate stylesheet"` makes the stylesheet **alternate**
3. any stylesheet with a `title` is **combined** (turned on/off) with all others with the same `title`
4. any stylesheet with a `media` attribute is **media-specific** and *only applies* when the media query condition is satisfied

I suspect there may be other settings I have missed out, alongside:

- **persistent**
- **preferred**
- **alternate**
- **combined**
- **media-specific**

*What are all the available settings for stylesheet `<link>` elements?*

Comment: I still worry that this is very broad.   I have no idea how long the list of "all the settings" is.   Usually questions that ask for a big list can't be answered in a few paragraphs.  I've reopened it for now.

Comment: A simple perusal of [the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) answers this question.

Comment: @Rob - I see nothing in the document section you have linked to (or anywhere in the wider document) that discusses the settings (_persistent_, _preferred_, _alternate_, _combined_ etc.) for `<link rel="stylesheet">`. Trust me, I wouldn't have posted the question above if I hadn't spent hours scouring the web first. What answer did you glean from your simple perusal of the WHAT-WG document you linked to?

Comment: You need to follow the links in the specification. For example, `rel` points to "allowed keywords" which [contains](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/links.html#linkTypes) some of your list.

Comment: Note: the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Rob - I think you know that `<link />` with a closing slash is from XHTML. If I may, I'll ask you again: What answers relating to stylesheet `<link>` settings did you glean from your simple perusal of the WHAT-WG document you linked to? Can you point to where it refers to _persistent_ and _preferred_ and _combined_ stylesheets? Or is it just that you skim-read the question above and instinctively linked to the WHAT-WG spec for the `<link>` element? I trust you can appreciate that stylesheet `<link>` element settings are one level of abstraction removed from possible `rel` values. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the closing slash is used in XHTML, which is XML, and nothing to do with HTML. I am sure you are not using XHTML. I have given you the source for all the attributes you are looking for here in the comments where you can find your own answer. If something is not listed there then, obviously, it is non-standard. I am not sure all those you listed exist.

Comment: @Rob - To clarify: I am looking to confirm _settings_ not `attributes` or their `values`. I refer you to the question at the top, where I enquire about _"the available **settings** for stylesheet `<link>` elements"_ and go on to cite a series of _settings_ like: _persistent_, _preferred_, _alternate_, _combined_ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MDN** has an authoritative summary of stylesheet `<link>` settings here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets

I'm not sure how I missed that - **MDN** is usually one of my first ports of call.

### Summary:

> ***Any stylesheet* in a document falls into *one* of the following categories:**
>
> - **Persistent** (no `rel="alternate"`, no `title=""`): always applies to the document.
> - **Preferred** (no `rel="alternate"`, with `title="..."` specified): applied by default, but disabled if an alternate stylesheet is
>     selected. **There can only be one preferred stylesheet**, so providing
>     stylesheets with different title attributes will cause some of them to
>     be ignored. See [Correctly Using Titles With External Stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web_Standards/Correctly_Using_Titles_With_External_Stylesheets) for a
>     more detailed discussion.
> - **Alternate** (`rel="alternate stylesheet"`, `title="..."` must be specified): disabled by default, can be selected.
>
> When style sheets are referenced with a `title` attribute on the `<link rel="stylesheet">` or `<style>` element, the title becomes one of the
>   choices offered to the user. Style sheets linked with the same `title`
>   are part of the same choice. Style sheets linked without a `title`
>   attribute are always applied.

**Source:** *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets*

The above doesn't go into **media-specific**, but it is the authoritative confirmation I was looking for.